# is kafka producer capable of sending multiple messages in a list?

Tags: producer, apache-kafka

In Kafka v 0.8.2, is it still possible/beneficial to send a list of ProducerRecords as a producer as opposed to only a single one at a time? Examining the API it seems like org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer does not have the ability to send multiple producerRecords using one send call.

However, in the producer under javaapi, it's possible to send a list of keyedMessages. Can someone explain the difference or point me in the right direction? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The producer under javaapi is the old implementation which has been superseded by the new one in clients. The new producer implementation can still batch messages together but will do this in the background and when doing a call to send you'll get a future back for every message.

Batch size and latency can be controlled with parameters "batch.size" and "linger.ms". See [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newproducerconfigs) for details.

Answer (score 1):

`0.8.2` does not support sending list of messages as in prevois version. Instead the `send(ProducerRecord<K,V> record, Callback callback)` is provided with a callback.

You can however use the old client but that is not recomended as the new kafka client is claimed to be faster and better than the previous one.